# How to change DropDown background color of picker in the .NetMaui

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

By default, dropdown background color of picker in .Netmaui seem to be set as Gray200; Please tell me how to change it by customized color.

I already set this:

`<Picker.Resources> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBrush" Color="#464E51"/> <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBrush" Color="Transparent"/>--> </Picker.Resources>`

but it's fail to change background color of the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some code in the  **Project/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml** file:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    ...
    xmlns:local="using:MauiApp11.WinUI">
    <!--Add the following three lines-->
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownBackground" Color="#464E51" />
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I's done. Thanks Shen.

Comment: Shen, please help me why event though I've set text color of Picker is White --> it still be Black when mouse move arround.

Comment: As far as i know, it's stiil a bug on Windows. You could follow this thread [Fix DatePicker TextColor property](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/7995).

Comment: Thanks Shen again for your quickly answer. And have others questions need your help: 1. As your suggestion, all of my pickers in projects have a same background for dropdown item --> then It's could not change when App became LightMode or DarkMode? 2.How to change text color in Dropdown Items?

Comment: Sorry @Le Anh Xuan, you should start a new thread for new question. We should adhere to Stack Overflow's rules.

Comment: Hi @Liqun Shen, Instead of only set: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownBackground" Color="#464E51" /> Have anyways to set Color value depending on AppThemeBinding?